# AWS Lambda function can't connect to and query SQLite DB file from S3

Tags: python, sqlite, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

My goal is to upload a SQLite database file to AWS S3, use AWS Lambda & python (`sqlite3`) to connect to the database, query it, and return some of its data.

Having uploaded the database file to S3, I wrote a python script (which is to become the Lambda function) that *successfully* downloads the database from S3, connects to it with `sqlite3`, and returns some query results.

The issue is that when I take the *exact same code* and put it in AWS Lambda, I get the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "malformed database schema (message_idx_undelivered_one_to_one_imessage) - near \"where\": syntax error",
  "errorType": "DatabaseError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 11, in lambda_handler\n    print(cursor.execute(\"select mycolumn from message limit 1\").fetchone())\n"
  ]
}
```

Here is the python script/Lambda function:

```
import sqlite3
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
    bucket = s3.Bucket("my-bucket")
    bucket.download_file("my_database.db", "/tmp/my_database.db")

    conn = sqlite3.connect("/tmp/my_database.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    print(cursor.execute("select mycolumn from message limit 1").fetchone())
```

Running this file locally works correctly. I have confirmed that both my local environment and Lambda are using these versions of the following:

```
boto3: 1.20.32
python: 3.9.13
sqlite3: 2.6.0
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/NCrWitsX) is the schema of the database I'm trying to read.

Why is Lambda producing this error while my local environment isn't? How can I go about getting python to connect to the database within the Lambda function?

Comment: `sqlite:  2.6.0` you mean `sqlite3: 2.6.0` ? what's your database schema, is message a view ?

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant `sqlite3`. `message` is a table in the database. I'm not super familiar with SQLite, so I'm not exactly sure how to describe the schema. As far as I know, there are no views in the database.

Comment: to show the schemas you juste need to open your database with the sqlite3 comment `sqlite3 file.db` and then issue the `.schema` command, that should show the full database structure

Comment: Ok, here's the output of that command: https://pastebin.com/NCrWitsX

Comment: this is this ddl which seems to not be understood `CREATE INDEX message_idx_undelivered_one_to_one_imessage ON message(cache_roomnames,service,is_sent,is_delivered,was_downgraded,item_type) where cache_roomnames IS NULL AND service = 'iMessage' AND is_sent = 1 AND is_delivered = 0 AND was_downgraded = 0 AND item_type == 0;` you may want to edit that to your question so that it's clear for every reader

Comment: it's not quite easy either to infer the sqlite3 version from the python sqlite3 package. you could add the result of this python statement in your question `print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)`.

Comment: You're using SQLite 3.7.17, which does not support partial indexes (the "where" clause on your index), that feature was added in [3.8.0](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_0.html)

Comment: indeed, if you're using the same version on both environment there is no way it works on one and not on the other. you may want to clarify versions on both sides.

Comment: for more references https://www.sqlite.org/partialindex.html

Comment: `print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)` yields `3.37.0` on my machine and yields `3.7.17` on Lambda, so it seems like this is the issue..? If I can get my lambda function to run with a newer version of `sqlite3` then this should work on Lambda. I'll give this a try and update my question with the results. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Indeed that's the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From pastebin extract here is your DDL in your database schema which triggers your error when opening your database

```sql
CREATE INDEX message_idx_undelivered_one_to_one_imessage
ON message(
    cache_roomnames,
    service,
    is_sent,
    is_delivered,
    was_downgraded,
    item_type
) where cache_roomnames IS NULL
    AND service = 'iMessage'
    AND is_sent = 1
    AND is_delivered = 0
    AND was_downgraded = 0
    AND item_type == 0;
```

The partial index feature has been integrated in sqlite since the 3.8.0 version https://www.sqlite.org/partialindex.html.
The sqlite3 version on the lambda environment is probably to old to handle such king of schema. An version bump in your sqlite3 dependency in your lambda environment should fix your issue.